# How to drag and drop different list box items together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 list boxes. It is placed adjacent to each other. User can sort each list individually and then I have provided a checkbox. If checkbox is checked, then the items gets bound each other horizontally and then onwards, if user select an element from one left list box, then the adjacent element from the right list box also gets selected and then moves together for reordering(sorting). Can you please help me in selecting both the elements and moving together.

Comment: You can find the concept on [this link](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). Modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do, do you mean like http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the question to make it more clear. I wanted to move items within the list but together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to do this in the following way.

I have used jquery-sortable for both lists.

in the activate callable, got the original listitems

```
activate: function(event, ui){
    srcList = $('#source-container ul.sourceList li');
},
```

in the stop callable

```
stop: function(event, ui){
    $(srcList).each(function(idx, elem){
         if($(elem).equals($(ui.item)))
     orgIndex = idx;
});
$('#source-container ul.sourceList li').each(function(idx, elem){
    if($(elem).equals($(ui.item)))
        curIndex = idx;
});
$('#target-container ul.targetList li').each(function(idx, elem){
    if(idx == orgIndex){
    var toIndex = curIndex + 1;
    var fromIndex = orgIndex + 1;
    if(toIndex < fromIndex)
         $('#target-container ul.targetList li:nth-child('+fromIndex+')').insertBefore($('#target-container ul.targetList li:nth-child('+toIndex+')'));
    else
    $('#target-container ul.targetList li:nth-child('+fromIndex+')').insertAfter($('#target-container ul.targetList li:nth-child('+toIndex+')'));
}
```